# Water pressure an salinity sensor connected to arduino

Tags: sensors

I am trying to design a project that Arduino would have connected water and salinity sensor, would be packed in a special box be droped into ocean up to 500 meters. What sensors should I use and how should they be conencted. I assume that I would need professional equipment, not chineese stuff from ebay.
Hardware needs to be able to work under 50*C and up to 50bar

Update:

Budget is about up to 400 pounds for sensors.
Resolution of pressure 0 to 100 bar
Resolution of salinity doesnt matter so much. Few percents of mistake, just to measure it somehow

Comment: What sort of resolution and accuracy do you need? How long is the deployment? Any communication?

Comment: pessure about 1bsi accuracy and accuracy of salinity doesnt matter. just something that measure quite properly under these conditions.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with bsi, it seems like 500m of saltwater would be a pressure of 5 MPa or 750 psi.    The arduino can interface electrically to most things, but for advice on selection of an uncommon, special sensor, you might do better in an engineering forum.

Comment: oh I meant bar, sorry. 50 bar, 5MPa

Comment: You may find [Robotics Stackexchange](http://robotics.stackexchange.com) useful for questions like this.

Comment: On "sea water", each 10m you have 1,007 bar. So at 500m you'll get about 50 x 1.007 = 50,35 bars.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you look for a sensor from Honeywell. The problem is that the pressure is very high for a board mounted sensor and the atmospheric pressure is varying. The board mounted sensors measure a maximum of 10 bar.  It is not clear what accuracy you require. Is there a connection to the surface? If so you should measure differential pressure between the seabed and the surface.  Can you be content with a maximum depth of 100 m?

I don't think salinity varies much offshore so it might not be worth measuring.